# No-name attributes no longer post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, braintree

I recently upgraded my code from Rails 3.x to Rails 4. Everything worked in Rails 3.x However, I now notice that my app no longer posts the no-name attribute parameters when I hit submit. The app is supposed to use Braintree.js (payment gateway script) to encrypt the no-name params just before posting. Any thoughts? Could this be connected with strong parameters in Rails 4? How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Kidada, I work at Braintree. Fields with no "name" attribute never posted; that happens in the browser so the version of rails doesn't matter. Braintree.js should add the "name" parameter for you; it's possible it's not working correctly due to some change you made when upgrading to Rails 4. I'd suggest you [reach out to our support team](http://support.braintreepayments.com/) or post your actual code here as well as the HTML source of the page so people can look for the issue.

Comment: I contacted Braintree Support prior to posting here. I believe I figured out what was happening. Rails 4 ships with the Turbolinks gem. This gem uses Ajax to speed up page rendering in most applications. It is automatically included when you create a Rails 4 app. The problem was that Turbolinks and Braintree.js were not playing nice. As a result, Braintree.js was not executing and so the encrypted credit card information could not be posted along with the other model bound parameters. I disabled Turbolinks (via gemfile and application.js), and Braintree is back to functioning normally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 4 ships with the Turbolinks gem. This gem uses Ajax to speed up page rendering in most applications. It is automatically included when you create a Rails 4 app. The problem was that Turbolinks and Braintree.js were not playing nice. As a result, Braintree.js was not executing and so the encrypted credit card information could not be posted along with the other model bound parameters. I disabled Turbolinks (via gemfile and application.js), and Braintree is back to functioning normally.